# How to fix Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `UglifyWriter` plugin in Ember application

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, uglifyjs

I am using ember framework for my frontend application, It wors fine till last week now when I tried to build the application getting below issue,

```
Build failed.
Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `UglifyWriter` plugin. 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (v)
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/vad/dev/book-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1545:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/vad/dev/book-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1553:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/vad/dev/book-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2092:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/vad/dev/book-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2100:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/vad/dev/content-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2106:9)
```

Please find the below package.json for your reference

```
{
  "name": "book-content",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Book management platform",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^1.0.2",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^1.1.1",
    "bson": "^4.0.4",
    "ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
    "ember-aupac-typeahead": "3.1.0",
    "ember-browserify": "^1.2.2",
    "ember-can": "^0.8.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.13.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-autocomplete-input": "1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.7.1",
    "ember-cli-pace": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-pagination": "2.2.2",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^7.1.7",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-composable-helpers": "2.1.0",
    "ember-concurrency": "0.8.21",
    "ember-data": "2.7.0",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-get-helper": "1.1.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.0",
    "ember-lodash": "4.17.1",
    "ember-moment": "^7.8.0",
    "ember-plupload": "1.13.18",
    "ember-power-select-typeahead": "0.7.1",
    "ember-query-params-reset": "2.0.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-rl-month-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "ember-rl-year-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "ember-slide-push-menu": "1.0.0",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.2.0",
    "ember-uploader": "1.0.0",
    "ember-validations": "v2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "glob": "^4.5.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "uglify-js": "2.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "minimist": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

I see some of the dependencies pulled the latest version of uglify:3.11.3 which could cause an issue but I don't know how to instruct them to use version 2.7.0 or the one which is not causing an issue. I don't know how to override nested dependency.

Could anyone please guide me to fix the issue?

**Fix 1:**

I have fixed the issue by adding the below code in `ember-cli-build.js`

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    minifyJS: {
      options: {
        exclude: ["**/vendor.js"]
      }
    }
  });
```

But I am not sure whether it's a good solution but it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are some code which is in vendor folder is using the latest ES6 syntax which was not transpiled using babel so ember-cli-uglify can't recognize it.

Fix you have done is, ember-cli-uglify will not run for vendor folder js files. ie., it will not run minification(removing comment and doing code change for reducing file size) for those files.

Comment: Does it will impact anything ? Or is it a really good fix ?

Comment: In browser you will receive the code exactly you have written and size also will be little high. if this is not bothers you then your fix is ok. Most of them wont do this. 
You may find the code causing this failure and modify it to old syntax.